# Error in Connection to SQL Server Database

Tags: java, php, jsp

When I attempt to connect to my database with the following code:

```
try
{
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.78;instanceName=SQL2014;databaseName=GIDS;user=sa;password=invent";
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
    System.out.println("Database connection = "+con );
}
catch( Exception e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println( "Error connecting to database.  Error: "+e.getMessage() );
}
```

I am getting the following exception:

> Error: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It has no error during compilation

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code

```
try
{
    String username = "sa";
    String password = "invent";
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.78;instanceName=SQL2014;databaseName=GIDS";
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl,username,password);
    System.out.println("Database connection = "+con );
}
catch( Exception e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println( "Error connecting to database.  Error: "+e.getMessage() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the jar that have the implementation classes (driver jar) to connect o ms sql in the class path.